# In a Hugo Academic-themed website, How do I put line breaks in org names?

Tags: hugo, static-site, toml

I have a Hugo site using the Academic theme (source here: https://github.com/davebraze/david-braze). In the config.toml file, I want to be able to force linebreaks in an organization name. Without line breaks, it looks like this:

```
organizations = [ { name = "Literacy Coalition of Greater New Haven", url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]
```

I'd like to force a line break (in the rendered html) before "of" in "Literacy Coalition of...".

I've tried:

```
organizations = [ { name = "Literacy Coalition\\of Greater New Haven", url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]

organizations = [ { name = "Literacy Coalition<br>of Greater New Haven", url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]

organizations = [ { name = "Literacy Coalition<br />of Greater New Haven", url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]

organizations = [ { name = "Literacy Coalition&#xa;of Greater New Haven", url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]
```

None of that works. The following ***almost*** works:

```
organizations = [ { name = ["Literacy Coalition","of Greater New Haven"], url = https://literacyeveryday.org" },
                  { name = "Haskins Laboratories", url = "https://www.haskinslabs.org/" }]
```

That renders with a line break where I want it, but it also surrounds the org name with square brackets in the rendered html, which I *don't* want.

Any help?